# Class Function does not return array properly

Tags: php, arrays

I can't seem to get the array to return from the function correctly, every time I run the script it just echoes out 0, even though I have checked that the MySQL query returned at least 1 row. I've also tried using `$_GLOBALS["FORUM_ANSWERS"][] = ...`, however it still did not work.

```
public function getAnswers() {
    $dbh = $this->dbh;
    $id = $this->question_id;
    $q = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM answers WHERE question_id = :id");
    $q->bindParam(":id", $id);
    $q->execute();
    $nr = $q->rowCount();
    if ($nr == 0) {
        echo "No Questions";
    }

    $_GLOBALS["FORUM_ANSWERS"] = [];
    while ($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        array_push($_GLOBALS["FORUM_ANSWERS"], array(
            "num_id" => $row["num_id"],
            "question_id" => $row["question_id"],
            "answer" => $row["answer"],
            "name" => $row["name"],
            "username" => $row["username"],
            "ip" => $row["ip"],
            "date" => $row["date"],
        ));
    }

    return $GLOBALS["FORUM_ANSWERS"];
}
```

**SEPERATE FILE:**

```
$answers = $forum->getAnswers();
echo count($answers);
```

Comment: On a side note, do you need to set this as a `$GLOBALS`?

Comment: if you `while ($row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { print_r($row);` does that produce the arrays?

Comment: @objective_d noticed the problem. That being said, if you are trying to set to `global` try not to. Setting to `global` is not best practice, so-to-speak.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are assigning to `$_GLOBALS` and returning `$GLOBAL`.

You actually don't need to use a global array by the look of it - I would just assign the array to a variable (that you initialise in the function) and return that.

Comment: I'm returning `$GLOBALS["FORUM_ANSWERS"];`, am I not?

Comment: Notice the underscore `$_GLOBALS` vs `$GLOBALS`